# Is that possible to rank the importance of independent variables with simple linear regression with standardized IVs

Tags: r, regression, multicollinearity, variance-inflation-factor

I run a multiple linear regression model with six independent variables using lm function in R (n=25). However, I found severe multicollinearity between my
IVs (based on VIF values). The presence of all the IVs is important and I cannot remove even one IV from the model.
I wonder if I can run the simple linear regressions for each IV separately ... the idea is just to get a general picture of which
predictors are important and to rank them. I am grateful if you could help me to resolve my issues,

1. Is it appropriate to run several simple linear regression models with the same independent (continuous) variables to rank the IVs. In this, all six IVs are first standardized before run several simple regressions.
2. I want to know if the simple regression method using standardized IVs allows the ranking of my IVs.

My goal is to know how each IV predicts the outcome variable. Can anyone help me to resolve my problem ?

Comment: How do you think the ranking will help you to predict the response? I don't see what you win from this. Neither is it clear why you can't remove any IV. What about using one or two principal components (not sure of course how exactly your "severe multicollinearity" plays out)? This would still keep all variables in the model, in some way.

Comment: The general problem about predictor importance is that if they are correlated, it means that some of them carry to some extent the same information, and when thinking about importance it is not clear to which variable this joint information should be assigned. Running single regressions will count information that is shared between variables fully for every single variable, which is not necessarily appropriate. This is an essential ambiguity for which there is no unique solution.

Comment: Hi Christian, thank you very much for your valuable explanation. I thought standardizing independent variables will help me to rank each IVs (using standardized coefficient). I just want see what is the important independent variable. All my IVs can influence the dependent variable. That is why I cannot remove it. Could you please little explain to me your last sentence " Running single regression....." to understand why it is not appropriate to select important predictor with several simple regression analysis. Many thanks for helping to a beginner level student.

Comment: I'm not saying it's not appropriate. The thing is that "variable importance" doesn't have a unique definition; running single regressions implies one definition but there are others. Two highly dependent variables may turn out both to be "very important" using single regressions even though you only need one of them to have a good model (because if you have one, you already have all or most information in the other). This may or may not be inappropriate depending on how you use and interpret your "ranking", which I haven't understood yet.

Comment: Hi Christian, thank you for replying to me. For your information, this is how I thought to "ranking" IVs. First I run several simple regressions to all my IVs. Then I will look to "standardized" regression coefficients and p-value for each IV.  Then I select only significant IVs. Then I will compare the standardized regression coefficients (absolute values), next, I put them in a order. The larger the coefficient is the important IV. Many thanks to you again.

Comment: Hi Christian, do you think I am in the correct way?

Comment: I have no idea, as I still don't really understand what this ranking is used for. The problem of "ranking importance" is somehow ill posed, as I had written before. I'm not saying it's wrong, I'm just saying it may not help you as much as you think. " Then I select only significant IVs." No idea why you do this, I thought you can't drop variables?

Comment: when I do several simple regressions, I mean that I only select variables that are significant. That's why I mean " " Then I select only significant IVs.". If I want to do multiple linear regression, dropping variables does not give me full information from the multiple regression model.